# SenchaTouch: dynamically binding a store

Tags: sencha-touch

I want to show a chart based on parameter passed from another panel; how can i bind dynamically a store instead of assigning it during the declaration of the panel?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't try with bindStore() property?